# in Typescript, can Object.prototype function return Sub type instance?

Tags: javascript, typescript, get, subtype, defineproperty

I want to write code like

```
class Place {
  next: Place;
  get to() : Place {
    return this;
  }
}
let places : Place[]= [];
..

places[0].to.next = new Place();
```

There are many similar classes, so I want define 'to' property to Object.prototype.

```
Object.defineProperty(Object.prototye,"to",{
  get: function() {
    return this;
  }
});
```

But compilation has failed because of `Property 'next' does not exist on type 'Object'`

Can I return subtype in Typescript with Object.prototype function or property?

Comment: You could define `interface Object { to: any }`, but this of course won't be type safe.  You'd better define a base class instead polluting the `Object` (every single object)

Answer (score 2):

Typescript can't model exactly the beahavior you want.

The closest I can think of is to use a method not a property. For methods we can define a `this` parameter and infer it's type and use it as the return type:

```
class Place extends Object{
  next: Place;
}
let places: Place[] = [];

interface Object{
  to<T>(this: T):T; 
}
Object.prototype.to = function () {
  return this;
};

places[0].to().next = new Place();
```

The simplest solution would be to actually use a base class for all such objects with the property typed as polymorphic `this`:

```
class Base {
  get to(): this { return this; }
}
class Place extends Base{
  next: Place;
}
let places: Place[] = [];
places[0].to.next = new Place();
```

**Note:** Polluting the global `Object` does not seem like a great idea  but ultimately that is your call.

Answer (score 0):

I found some solution.

TS have a return type "this";

```
class Entity {
  self() : this {
    return this;
  } 
}

class Place extends Entity {
  where(toGo:string) {
    ....
  }
}
```

and I can use place like

```
new Place().self().where("Canada");
```

method `self` is decleared at super class but it can return sub class type.

So, I can use place instance without type casting.

Comment: But it can not be placed at 'static' memeber, so I can not use "this" return type to prototype  :(