# TypeScript typing: Object.defineProperty function args

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've checked the all suggested answers here including:

[in Typescript, can Object.prototype function return Sub type instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927276/in-typescript-can-object-prototype-function-return-sub-type-instance)

however, can't figure out, so please let me ask new question.

Basically, I try to emulate Infix notation in JavaScript/TypeScript for functional programming.

This is a pretty dirty hack and the code is the below:

```js
  const customOperator = op => f =>
    Object.defineProperty(
      Object.prototype, op,
      {
        value: function (a) {
          return f(this)(a)
        },
        enumerable: false,
        configurable: false,
        writable: false
      });

  customOperator('+')
    (a => b => a + b);

  console.log(
    1['+'](2) // <--Infix notation
  );  //3
```

Obviously this occurs prototype pollution. Although it is out of topic, if you know a better way to avoid the problem, please let me know.

The question is, I want to use TypeScript type checking like below:

```
customOperator('+')
   ((a: number) => (b: number) => a + b);
```

Unfortunately, in TypeScript, the type-checking failed and no error detected on:

```
console.log(
    "foo"['+'](1)
); // "foo1"

console.log(
    1['+']("bar")
); // "1bar"
```

What is the proper way to make it behave?

TypeScript 3.8.3

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom"
    ],
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": false,
    "declaration": false,
    "noImplicitThis": true
  }
}
```

---

---

**SOLVED**

```
const customOperator = (op: string) => (f: Function) =>
    Object.defineProperty(
        Object.prototype, op,
        {
            value: function (a: undefined) {
                return f(this)(a)
            },
            enumerable: false,
            configurable: false,
            writable: false
        });
customOperator('+')
    ((a: number) => (b: number) => a + b);
interface Number {
    '+'(a: number): number;
}

console.log(
    1['+'](2)
); //no error

console.log(
    "foo"['+'](1)
); // type error!!

console.log(
    1['+']("bar")
); // type error!!
```

with

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom"
    ],
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "declaration": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there is any "right" way to do this, due to the nature of what you're doing, but is this what you're looking to do?

```
interface Number {
  '+'(a: number): number;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works flawlessly with tsconfig.json edit.  I edited my question for the detail.